# Flip an image using app engine image service

Tags: image, google-app-engine, blobstore

What do I need to append to an image URL to flip the image horizontally or vertically.  In the documentation it says you can add s## with -c to crop the image, but it doesn't talk about r90 r180 or r270 which works to rotate the image.  My question is how do I flip the image using url parameters?

**EDIT:** Please star this issue if you would like to see this implemented. [code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6886](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6886)

Comment: I am under the impression that since the doc stated "available arguments", it means that it is not possible to flip the image using URL parameters.

Comment: But the rotate arguments are not documented but still work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option that can be appended to the URl to flip an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `-fv` or `-fh` to the end of your URL, eg. `=s280-fh` to flip the image.

Full list here: [List of all the App Engine images service get_serving_url() URI options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148567/list-of-all-the-app-engine-images-service-get-serving-url-uri-options/25438197)