# Google Images API URL Parameters

Tags: image, google-app-engine

I am using the Images API documented here:https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/

According to the documents:

> You can then add arguments to this URL to get the desired size and
>   crop parameters. The available arguments are:
>
> =sxx where xx is an integer from 0–1600 representing the length, in pixels, of the image's longest side. For example, adding =s32 resizes
>   the image so its longest dimension is 32 pixels.
>   =sxx-c where xx is an integer from 0–1600 representing the cropped image size in pixels, and -c tells the system to crop the image.

It seems there are quite a few additional arguments available. For example, flipping an image with `-fv` or `-fh`, adding a 20px border with `-b20` and several more. I can't find these mentioned anywhere. Is this just an as-of-yet unpublished API, or is there a good reference out there that I've just been unable to find?

Comment: Thanks @AlexMartelli. I'm especially interested in the possibility of controlling jpeg compression/quality. It seems like there is a -v argument that effects the quality and file size, but I'm not really sure what it's doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of all the App Engine images service get\_serving\_url() URI options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148567/list-of-all-the-app-engine-images-service-get-serving-url-uri-options)