# how to get a image from google cloud storage in java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have little js programm that uploads an image to my gcs bucket. If thi happens, my gcs sends a notification to a servlet at google app engine.

So far, so good.
Now my servlet should read from gcs and download the file, which was uploaded a moment ago. Then i want to parse it into an image object and resize the image. The new image should be uploaded to another gcs bucket.

To communicate with gcs i use the gcs client lybrary.

```
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());
GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename("bucket_name", "image_name");
GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(filename, 0, 1024 * 1024);

try ( ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(readChannel))){
   inputStream.readObject();
   log(inputStream.getClass().getName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I also tried to save it in a byte array but the Error is always the same

> Uncaught exception from servlet
>   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: FFD8FFE0

what am I doing wrong? Did I forget something?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using App Engine's ImageService URLs to serve resized images may be an easier and cheaper option than resizing yourself and saving different versions.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, do you have link where this is explained in detail?

Comment: especially when it comes to saving data into blobstore from a browser client with javascript

Comment: See the getServingURL() method on this page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/#Java_Transforming_images_from_the_Blobstore. You can wrap a call to this method in a cloud endpoint API method and call it from a javascript client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ImageService like Price suggested:

```
GcsFilename gcsFilename = new GcsFilename(bucketDefault, objectName);
String filename = String.format("/gs/%s/%s", gcsFilename.getBucketName(), gcsFilename.getObjectName());
String servingUrl = imageService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(filename).secureUrl(true));
```

Then, you can use [these parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148567/list-of-all-the-app-engine-images-service-get-serving-url-uri-options#answer-25438197) to transform the served image on the fly.

Comment: GcsService is not found/availabe in android studio with app engine module.