# I want to get serving url for my images on firebase storage

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-storage

It is possible to get a serving url like http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-dB80E6geqWFVU41ZmWL1iGC0BkCDcXAGojwaAgMHG-wMe_xCpISffiaNy00Y6ATJ2J9_W_I8rMgwQYWQQyGcFuffw=s1024

It's done by using google app engine:

```
images.get_serving_url(blobkey, secure_url=False)
```

I don't want to use Google App Engine, just Firebase or the UI.

Can this be accomplished?

Thanks!

I got the info/idea from here:

http://www.photo-mark.com/notes/photo-site-app-engine/
[List of all the App Engine images service get_serving_url() URI options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148567/list-of-all-the-app-engine-images-service-get-serving-url-uri-options)

Answer (score 2):

With Firebase Storage that is known as a *download URL*. It is a public (but unguessable) URL for the file.

See the documentation on how to get download URLs for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files), [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) and [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files).

Firebase Storage doesn't currently have any way to automatically resize/transcode images (or transform other content) upon request.