# Is there any method equivalent to getServingUrl() in swift/objective c?

Tags: android, ios, swift, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Currently I'm using google app engine images for image transformations for my android app. The images will be trasformed on the fly and we can access the image with unique urls, which are generated by the getServingUrl() mathod. The documentation for which is available in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/. But there is no documentation on how it can be done in ios application. Is there any equivalent method to getServingUrl() in swift code? Or google app engine doesnt support IOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use:

`https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket name}/{image path}`

where the default bucket name is typically `your_app_name.appspot.com`, and the image path is the name you gave the image when you stored it, like `photos/avatars/user12345`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I need to transform images through url parameters (Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148567/list-of-all-the-app-engine-images-service-get-serving-url-uri-options/). But these image tranformations using url parameters are not found working in the url format you shared- https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket name}/{image path}. But I can access the original image using this url.  Have any clue?