# Is there any way to configure the pan/crop position when using Google App Engine Image API?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine and using `get_serving_url` to get a URL which I can append on to perform resizes and cropping. I'd like to be able to crop a square out of an image, but to also control what part of the image the crop is coming from, like passing in x/y values/

I've seen an [unofficial list of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148567/list-of-all-the-app-engine-images-service-get-serving-url-uri-options). I tried using the x/y/z options but they did not work and I'm not sure how to get them to. I don't see why GAE Image API wouldn't be able to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

From the oficial documentation of Images Python API there is no parameters to specify the x,y for the crop transformation when using [get_serving_url()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/#get-serving-url) method.

But if you use the crop method of [Image()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/#using-image) class, it accepts 4 parameters:

crop(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y)

Check the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images).

Notice that this is for Python API for App Engine Standard.