# Google App Engine Images API - cropping using a bounding box with percentages

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

In the python [google.appengine.api.images](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images) docs there are crop functions such as `crop(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y)`, which allow you to specify a **bounding box** for cropping using **percentages**.

In addition, same docs say that one can append e.g. '=s32' to the image url returned by `get_serving_url()` in order to resize the image to 32px in the larger dimension. There are also crop options, however none of them are given with a bounding box (i.e. crop that's not defined from the corner nor around the center of the image) nor with percentages (all examples are around pixels).

Is there a way to replicate `crop()`'s behavior by appending options to the serving url returned by the `get_serving_url()` function?

Comment: [`crop()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/images#Image.crop) and [`get_serving_url`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/appengine/standard/images/api/blobstore.py) are slightly two different things. I know what you mean, though. Since one of the parameters of `get_serving_url()` is `size`, you could replicate the same behavior, if you calculated the size for the bounding box that will crop the image beforehand and passed it in the `size` parameter.

Comment: @sllopis sorry if my question is not clear, but the url returned from get_serving_url can be appended with e.g. '=s32' to get an image of size 32 pixels in larger dimension. There are other options as well, however I can't find whether one could use these options to replicate the behavior of that crop() function in both aspects: 1. defined by a bounding box (so crop is not from corner nor center of image) 2. defined by percentages (rather than pixels). I'll edit the question a little to reflect that.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly what are you trying to do, but as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images#google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url), you can specify "crop" parameter as true, and it will request a cropped image.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's support, unfortunately it is not possible to crop a bounding box via serving_url as stated [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/17rjUSfHIdA) .

Another point to consider is that their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images#Python_Transforming_images_in_Python) of serving_url only support size and crop parameters only, but it works with a lot more [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148567/list-of-all-the-app-engine-images-service-get-serving-url-uri-options), so there is a possibility that it works as well, just be in mind that officially not.

And please, if you success on that, don't forget to share it here!