# Script does not show original image

Tags: javascript, css

Guys I have a script that shows blogger articles, only the images of the articles are of poor quality.

Looking at the script the only part that refers to the image is this

```js
// Get the post thumbnails
postimg = ("media$thumbnail" in entry) ? entry.media$thumbnail.url : imgBlank;

// Build the post template
output += '<div class="itemposts">';
output += '<h6><a href="' + posturl + '" title="' + posttitle + '">' + posttitle + '</a></h6>';
output += '<div class="iteminside"><a href="' + posturl + '"><img src="' + postimg + '" /></a>';
output += '<span class="summary">' + postsumm + '</span></div>';
output += '<div style="clear:both;"></div><div class="itemfoot">' + timepub + replies + '<a class="itemrmore" href="' + posturl + '">' + rmoreText + '</a></div>';
output += '</div>';
```

css code:

```css
.itemposts img {
  float:left;
  height:90px;
  width:200px;
  margin:2px 10px 2px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow:none;
  -moz-box-shadow:none;
  box-shadow:none;
  background-color:#fafafa;
  border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
  padding:4px;
}
```

Does anyone know which part of the code needs to be changed to show the image with the original quality?

added full code full code

```
<script>
var showPostDate   = true,
    showComments   = true,
    idMode         = true,
    sortByLabel    = false,
    labelSorter    = "Games",
    loadingText    = "Loading...",
    totalPostLabel = "Jumlah posting:",
    jumpPageLabel  = "Halaman",
    commentsLabel  = "Komentar",
    rmoreText      = "Selengkapnya &#9658;",
    prevText       = "Sebelumnya",
    nextText       = "Berikutnya",
    siteUrl        = "https://elfenliedbrazil.blogspot.com/",
    postPerPage   = 6,
    numChars       = 370,
    imgBlank       = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAADElEQVQImWOor68HAAL+AX7vOF2TAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
// Original: 
// Modified by Taufik Nurrohman
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var minpage = 6; // Minimum number to display the page
var maxpage = 10; // The maximum number of pages to display
var firstpage = 0; // Detect the first time it is executed
var pagernum = 0; // Contain the page number where we
var postsnum = 0; // Start the first page
var actualpage = 1; // Starting value of the current page (it will change if you click the pagination).

// This is the container template that will be used to insert the posts template, pagination and the posts count
document.write('<div id="toc-outer"><div id="results"></div><div id="itempager" style="position:relative;"><div id="pagination"></div><div id="totalposts"></div><a title="Taufik Nurrohman" style="display:block!important;visibility:visible!important;opacity:1!important;position:absolute;bottom:10px;right:14px;font:normal bold 8px Arial,Sans-Serif!important;color:#666;text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);text-decoration:none;" href="http://hompimpaalaihumgambreng.blogspot.com/2012/03/daftar-isi-blogger-dengan-navigasi.html" target="_blank">&#9658;TN</a></div></div>');

var _results = document.getElementById('results');
var _pagination = document.getElementById('pagination');
var _totalposts = document.getElementById('totalposts');

// Build the table of contents framework

function showPagePosts(json) {

    var entry, posttitle, posturl, postimg, postsumm, replies, monthnames, timepub, output = "";

    if (pagernum === 0) {
        postsnum = parseInt(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t);
        pagernum = parseInt(postsnum / postPerPage) + 1;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < postPerPage; i++) {

        if ("entry" in json.feed) {

            if (i == json.feed.entry.length) break;

            entry = json.feed.entry[i];
            posttitle = entry.title.$t; // Get the post title

            // Get rel="alternate" for truly post url
            for (var k = 0, elen = entry.link.length; k < elen; k++) {
                if (entry.link[k].rel == "alternate") {
                    posturl = entry.link[k].href; // This is your real post URL!
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Get the comments count
            for (var l = 0, clen = entry.link.length; l < clen; l++) {
                if (entry.link[l].rel == "replies" && entry.link[l].type == "text/html") {
                    var commentsnum = entry.link[l].title.split(" ")[0]; // This is your comments count
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If the Blogger-feed is set to SHORT, then the content is in the summary-field
            postsumm = ("summary" in entry) ? entry.summary.$t.replace(/<br ?\/?>/ig, " ").replace(/<.*?>/g, "").replace(/[<>]/g, "") : ""; // Get the post summary

            // Reduce post summaries to "numChars" characters.
            // "numChars" is a variable. You determine the value
            if (postsumm.length > numChars) {
                postsumm = (numChars > 0 && numChars !== false) ? postsumm.substring(0, numChars) + '...' : "";
            }

            // Get the post date (e.g: 2012-02-07T12:56:00.000+07:00)
            var _postdate = entry.published.$t,
                _cdyear = _postdate.substring(0, 4), // Take 4 characters from the "postdate" beginning, it means the year (2012)
                _cdmonth = _postdate.substring(5, 7), // Take 2 character 5 step from "postdate" beginning, it mean the month (02)
                _cdday = _postdate.substring(8, 10); // Take 2 character 8 step from "postdate" beginning. it means the day (07)

            // Month array template
            monthnames = (idMode) ? ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Agt", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Des"] : ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

            // The final product of the post date = (07 Feb 2012) (cdday monthnames cdyear)
            timepub = (showPostDate) ? _cdday + ' ' + monthnames[parseInt(_cdmonth, 10) - 1] + ' ' + _cdyear + ' - ' : '';

            // The final product of the comments count & comments label (10 Komentar) (commentsnum commentsLabel)
            replies = (showComments) ? commentsnum + ' ' + commentsLabel : '';

            // Get the post thumbnails
            postimg = ("media$thumbnail" in entry) ? entry.media$thumbnail.url : imgBlank;

            // Build the post template
            output += '<div class="itemposts">';
            output += '<h6><a href="' + posturl + '" title="' + posttitle + '">' + posttitle + '</a></h6>';
            output += '<div class="iteminside"><a href="' + posturl + '"><img src="' + postimg + '" /></a>';
            output += '<span class="summary">' + postsumm + '</span></div>';
            output += '<div style="clear:both;"></div><div class="itemfoot">' + timepub + replies + '<a class="itemrmore" href="' + posturl + '">' + rmoreText + '</a></div>';
            output += '</div>';

        }

    }

    // Put the whole template above into <div id="results"></div>
    _results.innerHTML = output;
    _create_pagination();

}

// Build the pagination
function _create_pagination() {

    output = "";
    var starter = 0;

  output += ((actualpage > 1) ? '<a title="' + prevText + '" class="prevjson" href="javascript:_init_script(' + (actualpage - 1) + ')">' + prevText + '</a>' : '<span class="prevjson hidden">' + prevText + '</span>') + '<em style="font:inherit;color:inherit;" class="pagernumber">';

    if (pagernum < (maxpage + 1)) {
        for (starter = 1; starter <= pagernum; starter++) {
            output += (starter == actualpage) ? '<span class="actual">' + starter + '</span>' : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + starter + ')">' + starter + '</a>';
        }
    } else if (pagernum > (maxpage - 1)) {
        if (actualpage < minpage) {
            for (starter = 1; starter < (maxpage - 2); starter++) {
                output += (starter == actualpage) ? '<span class="actual">' + starter + '</span>' : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + starter + ')">' + starter + '</a>';
            }
            output += ' ... ';
            output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + parseInt(pagernum - 1) + ')">' + parseInt(pagernum - 1) + '</a>';
            output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + pagernum + ')">' + pagernum + '</a>';
        } else if (pagernum - (minpage - 1) > actualpage && actualpage > (minpage - 1)) {
            output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(1)">1</a>';
            output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(2)">2</a>';
            output += ' ... ';
            for (starter = actualpage - 2; starter <= actualpage + 2; starter++) {
                output += (starter == actualpage) ? '<span class="actual">' + starter + '</span>' : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + starter + ')">' + starter + '</a>';
            }
            output += ' ... ';
            output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + (pagernum - 1) + ')">' + parseInt(pagernum - 1) + '</a>';
            output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + pagernum + ')">' + pagernum + '</a>';
        } else {
            output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(1)">1</a>';
            output += '<a href="javascript:_init_script(2)">2</a>';
            output += ' ... ';
            for (starter = pagernum - (minpage + 1); starter <= pagernum; starter++) {
                output += (starter == actualpage) ? '<span class="actual">' + starter + '</span>' : '<a href="javascript:_init_script(' + starter + ')">' + starter + '</a>';
            }
        }
    }

    output += '</em>' + ((actualpage < starter - 1) ? '<a title="' + nextText + '" class="nextjson" href="javascript:_init_script(' + (actualpage + 1) + ')">' + nextText + '</a>' : '<span class="nextjson hidden">' + nextText + '</span>');

    _pagination.innerHTML = output;
    _totalposts.innerHTML = totalPostLabel + ' ' + postsnum + ' - ' + jumpPageLabel + ' ' + ((actualpage * postPerPage) - (postPerPage - 1)) + ((actualpage < starter - 1) ? ' - ' + (actualpage * postPerPage) : "");

}

// Functions to remove and append the callback script that has been manipulated in the `start-index` parameter
function _init_script(n) {

    var parameter = (n * postPerPage) - (postPerPage - 1), old, s,
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        url = (sortByLabel) ? siteUrl + '/feeds/posts/summary/-/' + labelSorter + '?start-index=' + parameter : siteUrl + '/feeds/posts/summary?start-index=' + parameter; // Optional: Sort posts by a specific label

    if (firstpage == 1) {
        // Jump to top
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = _results.offsetTop - 30;
        document.body.scrollTop = _results.offsetTop - 30;
        // Remove the old callback script
        old = document.getElementById("TEMPORAL");
        old.parentNode.removeChild(old);
    }

    _results.innerHTML = '<div id="loadingscript">' + loadingText + '</div>';
    _pagination.innerHTML = '';
    _totalposts.innerHTML = '';

    s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = url + '&max-results=' + postPerPage + '&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showPagePosts';
    s.id = 'TEMPORAL';
    head.appendChild(s);
    firstpage = 1;
    actualpage = n;

}

// Execute the _init_script() function with parameter as `1` on page load
// So it will show the first page.
window.onload = function() {
    _init_script(1);
};
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing here, the issue is the original - why don't' you simply look at the original to verify?

Comment: `media$thumbnail` could be a reason for low quality, which suggests these are thumbnail images, try to print `entry` and see if there is original image URL present if yes then use that, if not then you need to have original size URL for the images.

Comment: It would be useful to answerers to provide the following information: (1) what browser you are running, (2) where does entry come from and what is it (3) if you can show us the original image and the low quality one please do.

Comment: I added the full code.

Comment: These are images from the blogger, it looks like the script pulls the thumbnail image instead of the original, the script should do that. but I can't find where I can modify

Answer (score 1):

> Thumbnails are reduced-size versions of pictures or videos
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumbnail

So you need to get the original image

In some cases you have the size in the url, like in this one at the end of url

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mC69w8Asl2c4y8it_gEb0-2CcwxKWUvz1fs4gOwVfxUkvSN7qAAl41VohsqSdVG-dZs=w720-h110-rw
```

You can simply remove that part and get the full size of the image

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mC69w8Asl2c4y8it_gEb0-2CcwxKWUvz1fs4gOwVfxUkvSN7qAAl41VohsqSdVG-dZs
```

> update

In your case you have a url like this

```
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/xxxxxxx/s72-c/xxxxx.jpg
```

you can change to

```
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/xxxxxxx/s640/xxxxx.jpg
```

This post explain very well how you can use [List of all the App Engine images service get_serving_url() URI options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148567/list-of-all-the-app-engine-images-service-get-serving-url-uri-options)

Comment: These are images from the blogger, it looks like the script pulls the thumbnail image instead of the original, the script should do that. but I can't find where I can modify